# How to prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges iif $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you please give me some hint how to prove this statement:

If $0<a_n<1$ for each n,

then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges iif $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$ converges.

Since $0<\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}\le \frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$,then from convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$ we may conclude by comparison test convergence of
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$.

But I failed to understand how conclude from convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$.

Thanks.

Comment: one direction is clear, for the other if $\sum\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ converges, so $a_n$ goes to zero, for large $n$ $\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}\le 2a_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $\Leftarrow:0<a_n<1\implies\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}<\dfrac{a_n}{1-a_n}~\forall \ n$ (*Use Comparison Test of the First Type*)
- $\Rightarrow:\dfrac{\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}}{\dfrac{a_n}{1-a_n}}=\dfrac{1-a_n}{1+a_n}=\dfrac{1-a_n}{1+a_n}=1-\dfrac{2a_n}{1+a_n}\to1~(\ne0)$ as $n\to\infty.$

  Thus ${\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}},{\dfrac{a_n}{1-a_n}}$ converges or diverges together. (*Use Limit Form*)

Comment: Nice! but in this case no need for the first part :)

Comment: @aflous: First part doesn't follow from the second unless the convergence of $\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ is given.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that given the convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{1+a_n},$
 you can prove that $a_n$ goes to $0$ as n goes to $\infty$
$$(\forall n,\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}>\dfrac{a_n}{2}>0)$$

and since $a_n$ is bounded from above by $1$, you could find a bound $\alpha>0$ such that:
$$\forall \ n, \ 1-a_n > \alpha$$

Now write 
$$\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}=\frac{a_n}{1+a_n} \frac{1+a_n}{1-a_n}<2 \alpha \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$$

The result follows

Comment: I'm not following you. What about $a_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$? It's bounded from above by $1$, but there's no such $\alpha$...

Comment: Yes!! I rectified that. thx

Answer (score 1):

To prove convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$ given convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{1+a_n},$ consider using the limit comparison test.  First think about what you know about $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n.$  (Hint: for all $n,$ $\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}>\dfrac{a_n}{2}>0.)$